# How to make the file address dynamic so that it fetches same file from different folder after every execution?

Tags: python, mysql, filesystems

As the title says, how to make a file folder name address dynamic in **python** so that it saves the file to database and update the address folder name(in numbers) to be remembered for next script execution?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Would a sym-link work? Or do you want the file to run a program to get where it should actually point to? If it's the latter, that's too high level for most filesystems.

Comment: I want to store the file in database and then want to update the file address, so that when I run the script again later it takes the goes to the next folder and check for the file and store that. There is pattern in the name of folder.